# Repositioning caption div with imagemapster jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been playing with the [Beatles example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/) referenced on the [imagemapster website](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#beatles). Is there a way to position the caption div to display on top of the image?

In the above jsfiddle, I've tried:

```
<div id="beatles-caption" style="clear:both; border:red; width:400px; 
         padding: 6px; position:relative; top:-100px;">
```

I've also experimented with z-index, but have not been successful in moving the caption onto the image.

In my own application, I have a full page background image and I need to identify various parts of the image in a caption div that is superimposed over the top right of the image.

Is there a better example for me to follow, given this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `position:relative; top:-100px;` would move the caption above the image is correct. You're only missing the `z-index`.

```
#beatles-caption { position:relative; top:-100px; z-index:1000; background:white; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/409/

You could also use a negative margin:

```
#beatles-caption { position:relative; margin-top:-100px; z-index:1000; background:white; }​
```

Or wrap the whole thing in a div with `position:relative` and `position:absolute; bottom:0` on the caption

http://jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/411/

Comment: Thank you. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcmit/mh4Ws/3/) was what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/408/

Note: It doesn't account for variable height. You can wrap the plugin in a container and set position:relative then change top to bottom:0.